# Splitting string when the parameter is backslash

Tags: python

I have been trying to do a very simple task but seems pretty hard. I am trying to split a string at the backslash (`'\\'`). I have found few similar posts to this topic but no one was actually addressing a comprehensive issue.

This is the string I want to chop up:

```
'13\nBono\nGoalkeeper\nApr 5, 1991 (29)\n€15.00m  '
```

The problem is if I use `.split('\\')` with the string above I get a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I have also tried:

- Double backslash `\\\`
- Triple quotes `"""\\"""`

But it doesn't work either.

I know I can add `r` in front of a string but would not be suitable as the string is part of a huge list and would have to add to each string the `r` in front of it.

In conclusion, is there a simple way to simply chop up words using the backslash as the delimiter?

Comment: `.split('\\')` is the correct way to split on a backslash. But your data does not contain backslashes. The sequence  `\n` represents a newline, not the 2 characters \ followed by n. Do `.split('\n')` to split at newlines.

Comment: Oh, this is great too. I did not know about \n. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do:

```
'your string'.split('\n')
```

because you don't have a backslesh `'\\'` but a newline escape charater `'\n'`